# html2canvas not full length - text is cut off

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I'm really struggling getting [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to the full length.

The resulting image is always cut off about mid way through. I can't get it to show the full length of the text, regardless of what's in the text.

Anyway to fix/debug this?

My code

```
$('body').append('<div id ="htmlTextBoxHolder">'+text+'</div>');


$('#htmlTextBoxHolder').css({
    'width': '1200px',
    'background-color':'#ffffff',
    'color': '#000000',
    'font-size': '60px'
});


html2canvas($("#htmlTextBoxHolder"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
        window.open(img);


        $('#posterHolder').empty();


    },

    width: $('#htmlTextBoxHolder').width(),
    height: $('#htmlTextBoxHolder').height()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Body has the overflow:hidden attribute. I added it to something else and it's fine.